# Doctrine2: Building object from array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible with Doctrine2 to use a method which creates an entity out of an array?

I mean somehow Doctrine2 converts the database return values to objects. Including children.

If it is possible a link and en example would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing built in since doctrine entities as just plain objects.  But you could certainly make your own factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine's DBAL and ORM layers are just abstractions over PDO. When specifying `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` as the `fetch_argument`, the `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` method will fetch the returned result set into the specified class.

See [Example #4 Instantiating a class for each result](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) in the docs for further information.

I assume that this is what Doctrine2 does under the hood, and as such it's a PDO feature, not a Doctrine2 feature.

As Cerad pointed out in the comment above, since Doctrine2 Entities are just POPOs, you'd have to perhaps create a factory, pass data into a constructor or some other method to fill your entity from an array.

I've done something similar to the following in the past:

```
<?php

class State
{
    private $name;

    private $abbreviation;

    public function fromArray(array $data)
    {
        foreach ($data as $prop => $value) {
            if (!property_exists($this, $prop)) {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException(
                    sprintf('Property %s does not exist in State', $prop)
                );
            }

            $this->{$prop} = $value;
        }
    }
}

$state = new State();
$state->fromArray([
    'name' => 'Arizona',
    'abbreviation' => 'AZ',
]);

var_dump($state);
```

This yields:

```
object(State)#1 (2) {
  ["name":"State":private]=>
  string(7) "Arizona"
  ["abbreviation":"State":private]=>
  string(2) "AZ"
}
```

Hope this helps :)